# Error of mysql connectivity with via .net connector on system start

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, mysql-connector

I am getting following error

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 111.22.3.44:3306
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateSocketStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, IPAddress ip, Boolean unix)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetTcpStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at CC.DataAccess.ConnectionManager.GetConnection()
```

My db server is on Centos with version 5.6.25
I am using .net 4.5 with mysqlconnecot 6.9.7. have anybody else faced this issue

Answer (score 0):

where is ur code brother? can u please paste your sample code here?

You may get some hints from :

[Unable to connect to MySQL database from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809353/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-asp-net)

[Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts. C# MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993657/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-c-sharp-mysql)

Comment: they have no use. Looks like some problem in there connector