# (No error message available, result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21)

Tags: .net, azure, connection-string

Azure Database connection string from .net Console application. Throwing error

> (No error message available,
>    result code: DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21).)

Installed the ODBC Client and Native CLient also.

Comment: Azure SQL database requires you to setup firewall exceptions. Have you done it? Take a look on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Comment: Also, try to search the error code itself `DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED(0x80040E21)`. It leads to https://forums.asp.net/t/1956492.aspx?No+error+message+available+result+code+DB_E_ERRORSOCCURRED+0x80040E21+ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23570878/why-connecting-to-an-oledb-is-giving-me-an-connection-error

Comment: We need a bit more info to be able to help you. For instance: how are you connecting to the database? Will it be using an EF model, of are you using plain ADO.NET? And, without showing any credentials, what is the connectionstring you're using? And did you add the client id to the Azure SQL Server firewall rules? Please add relevant code and configuration.