# Unable to connect to SQL Server in Hydro GeoAnalyst

Tags: sql-server, connection, database-connection, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2014-express

I have installed **Hydro GeoAnalyst 2014.2** and i have started trial and wanted to install demo project. Firstly, i must select data source type, available server and database name. I select data soruce type, then i write sql server instance name and then related combobox filled my databases. Finally, i select my database. 
**I use Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express** but Hydro GeoAnalyst return an error when i want to connect my database on MS SQL. Then i have installed **Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express** and Hydro GeoAnalyst returned the same error:

> Unable to Connect 'AYSE/SWS'. Ensure that the SQL Server exists and is running.

I have controlled my MS SQL Server 2012 and 2014 on SQL Server Management Studio and they works with no problems. I have controlled SQL Server Configuration Manager but no solution. **Why do i take this error ? Is this because of express edition of SQL Server ?** 
Please help. Thanks in advance.

I send error picture:

[image]

Comment: Would it help if you tried it with SQL Server authentication? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx In the screenshot you have tried with Windows Authentication.

Comment: i have tried both of them: windows authentication and sql server authentication. Result didn't change.

Comment: If you can connect with Data Link Properties wizard to your database as  advised in the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database , then I think it should work with  Hydro GeoAnalyst. If it does not, then I would try to contact the software provider: sws-support@slb.com, http://www.swstechnology.com/help/hga/2014/index.html?appendixb.htm

Comment: It is not about connection string.i have no work in code-behind. also i have backup of my database. During installation, i have selected localDB. thanks anyway

Comment: okay, sorry never used GeoAnalyst so it was a bit tricky for me :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server Express installed on another machine (not your local machine) make sure you have it configured for remote connections (http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/).
Also Please be aware that the vendor support email for Hydro GeoAnalyst has changed to support@waterloohydrogeologic.com. If you continue to experience difficulties contact them and they will be happy to look into the issue further.