# how can I find out the database I am using in vs2013

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I develop projects in visual studio 2013.
In web.config, in "connectionString" isn't information about database I am using.
If some one now how can I find out the database I am using, pleese help me.

Comment: web.config connectionString containes all the information you need to find the database. post it without username/password so we can look at it

Comment: Hopefully this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database

Comment: I am looking for name of database as "Oracle", MySql" ... I am using

Comment: post your connection string?

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=tcp:ynneovjgry.database.windows.net,1433;Database=*****;User ID=*******;Password=*******;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=340;" />

Comment: Thanks you all for halping me. I found very mach information about databases