# Adding data to a Microsoft's SQL Server file using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert-statement

I have added a Microsoft's SQL Server file to my project and I am running an `SqlCommand` to insert my data into the file. I am `using System.Data.SqlClient;`. The following code is how I add data to my file. After my program finished running then I go to the Data Explorer in my project and ask to Show Table Data of `HistQuote` and nothing show up. Could anyone advice on how I can verify that my `INSERT` statement is working.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.StorageConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    for (int intCurrentQuote = 0; intCurrentQuote < this.clbStockSelect.CheckedItems.Count; ++intCurrentQuote)
    {
        for (int intCurrentDate = 0; intCurrentDate < Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistStockDate.Count; ++intCurrentDate)
        {
            string strInsert = "INSERT INTO [HistQuote] ";
            string strColumns = "(Symbol, [Date], [Open], High, Low, Volume, Adj_Close, [Close]) ";
            string strValues = "VALUES (@Symbol, @Date, @Open, @High, @Low, @Volume, @Adj_Close, @Close)";

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strInsert + strColumns + strValues, connection))
            {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Symbol", SqlDbType.NChar));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Open", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@High", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Low", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Close", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Volume", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Adj_Close", SqlDbType.Real));
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Symbol"].Size = 10;

            sqlCommand.Prepare();

            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Symbol"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistSymbol;
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Date"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistStockDate[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Open"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistOpen[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@High"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistHigh[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Low"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistLow[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Close"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistClose[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Volume"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistVolume[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@Adj_Close"].Value = this.Quotes[intCurrentQuote].HistAdjClose[intCurrentDate];
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your connection string?

Comment: My connection string is `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Storage.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True`

Answer (score 1):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Storage`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Storage;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also see Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits to kick: using AttachDbFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info.

Comment: I thought that it was due to something like this. For your proposed solution _install SQL Server Express_ I have installed SQL Server 2012. I have been looking online to _install SQL Server Management Studio Express_ but I have to pay attention to what version I am using. I have found the following links [SSMS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8961) but its a _management tool for SQL Server 2005_ my 1st difference. Would you reccomend installing [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)

Comment: @Andraro: if you have a full version of SQL Server 2012 installed (other than Express) then that should include the full version of Management Studio - no need to install Express and Mgmt Studio Express in that case...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Would it be possible to let me know how you deteriminated the `Data Surce` of the connection string that you gave in your answer?

Comment: For future referance you can use the following link to [Find the connection string of the DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this possibly work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dataread
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.StorageConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string strCmd = "Select * from [HistQuote]";

            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strCmd, connection))
            {
                var rdr = new SqlDataReader();
                rdr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while(rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr["Symbol"].ToString() + rdr["Date"].ToString() + rdr["Open"].ToString() + rdr["High"].ToString() + rdr["Low"].ToString() + rdr["Volume"].ToString() + rdr["Adj_Close"].ToString() + rdr["Close"].ToString());
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The `rdr.Read()` returned false.