# Creating application without SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I created a window application in which I used SQL Server as backend database. But I want to know that is there a way through which we do not need SQL Server Management Studio to be installed on system?

I used Entity Framework with a code-first approach which creates database automatically but needs connection string for that. I need a way through which I can provide connection string of SQL Server Express without installing Management Studio.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE for developers / admins to interface with SQL Server. Applications don't need SSMS _at all_ to function - they just need a proper connection string and use database-related objects to connect.

Comment: Downvoting per clear lack of research.

Comment: Try [using the Data Link Properties wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10480011/205233)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to install SQL Server, Management Studio is just for an easier database and server management, but it's not required to make SQL Server services work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). You can create, manage and deploy SQL Server code right from Visual Studio.

It's built into VS 2013 and up and can be downloaded as an addin all the way down to VS 2010.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx