# how to get a content from textboxes in a database table with a Button click event?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, button

I[What i wanna do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgQhL.png)

So I tried this code
but it coudnt get a connection with the Database. I the connection string is correct

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;database=menucreator");


        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into [kunde]Vorname()values(@nm)";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", Vorname.Text);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();

        cmdd.CommandText = "insert into [kunde]Nachname()values(@nmm)";

        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nmm", Nachname.Text);
        cmdd.Connection = con;

        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (a == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dateien bitte");

        }
```

Comment: I don't see a password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the following code. It inserts two columns into a table (tableName). Maintain proper space in SQL query as showing in below sample code. ALso, it's best practice to keep the code in a try-catch block to capture any error that occurs during DB operation.

```
 try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;database=menucreator");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into tableName(column1,column2) values(@nm,@nmm)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm", Vorname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nmm", Nachname.Text);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (a == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dateien bitte");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error:"+ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: The problem is in 
con.Open();
it says that their is no connection possibel with the database

Comment: This is an issue with you connection string you are passing to SqlConnection for connecting to DB.

First, try to connect the server in SQL server management studio and make sure SSMS able to connect to DB using said credentials.

Alternatevily you can connect the SqlServer in Visual studio and then can copy the connection string from there (Server Explorer)
For info to copy the connection string please follow:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database)

Comment: Also in your connection string, you are not mentioning the password

Standard connection string should be like this:

`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Comment: There is no password . and i even tried your connection string but i still dont have  a connection to the database.