# How do I use a database in a C++/CLR project in Visual Studio?

Tags: database, visual-studio, winforms, c++-cli

I am trying to make an app that stores some text, so I would like to use database connection (**File I/O is discouraged)**? And, How do i learn that and **where to learn from?**
I don't know how to start, what to start and all, I have made GUI and want to make it working!

Comment: I'd do it from C#.

Comment: I use VS to develop Windows apps.  I program in C# and in C++ (and other languages).  If you are using [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), to me that means you probably ought to be using C# (or F#).  Your best place to start would be with a good introductory and/or tutorial book.  If you choose F#, I recommend [The Book of F#](https://nostarch.com/fsharp).  If you choose C#, I don't have a particular book recommendation — probably something from Microsoft Press or O'Reilly.

Comment: @Darpan, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the following code to insert some information from textbox to database.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        String^ connstr = "connstr";
        SqlConnection^ connection = gcnew SqlConnection(connstr);
        connection->Open();
        String^ sql = "Insert into Employee(ID,Name,Address)values(@ID,@Name,@Address)";
        SqlCommand^ command = gcnew SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command->Parameters->AddWithValue("@ID", txtID->Text);
        command->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Name",txtName->Text);
        command->Parameters->AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress->Text);
        command->ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection->Close();
        MessageBox::Show("success");



    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        dataGridView1->DataSource = 0;
        String^ connstr = "connstr";
        SqlConnection^ connection = gcnew SqlConnection(connstr);
        connection->Open();
        String^ sql = "Select * from Employee";
        //SqlCommand^ command = gcnew SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter^ adapter = gcnew SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable^ table = gcnew DataTable();
        adapter->Fill(table);
        dataGridView1->DataSource = table;
        connection->Close();

    }
```

Note:Button1_click is used to insert data to database. Button2_click is used to show data from database in the datagridview. Please use `\\` to replace `\` in the connectionstring.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jack! Your answer was useful, but I couldn't vote the answer. Sorry for that!

Comment: @Darpan, is there any other question about my answer? If not, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: Jack, nothing more, but I am **new** to this, so sorry to ask you one more question
How do I specify the source of the database, or how will my program locate it?? Could you please help me in this?

Comment: @Darpan, you could refer to the link to know how to get connection string from database. [How to get the connection String from a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479763/how-to-get-the-connection-string-from-a-database)