# linq to mysql. Keyword not supported: 'server'

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Here is a similar question [Keyword not supported: 'server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646833/keyword-not-supported-server). I use MySQL, when i use a `connectionString` to build a connection to database, there will be an exception:Keyword not supported: 'server'. I also try use `data source` to instead `server`, but it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

Comment: post your connection string

Comment: I'm not sure but this might be case sensitive so instead of server type Server

Comment: @utility my connectionString is  "server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;User Id=root;password=***;database=xxxxxx";

Comment: @MajkeloDev it's not case sensitive

Comment: try adding :   providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" with con string

Comment: @utility it doesn't work.

Comment: replace server with host

Comment: If it is similar to the question you linked: do you have that connection string in an App.config? If so, try connectionString="provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;UserId..." instead.

Comment: @LocEngineer I have app.config file and have tried the method you mentioned, but it doen's work.

Comment: Please be more specific. Have you made sure to use "MySql" as provider instead of "System.Data.SqlClient" which I accidentally copied from my config without adapting to your needs? Have you also used "&quot" in your connection string instead of clear text quotes? Is your path to the db correct? What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @LocEngineer my connectionString is  "provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;;User Id=xxx;password=xxx;database=xxx". I get an exception : "System.ArgumentException" type of unhandled exception occurs in System.Data.dll in.

Other information: Keyword not supported: "data source".

Comment: Well there you go. You said "I use MySQL", therefore System.data.SqlClient is wrong for you. It should instead be "Provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Server=mydb;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;database=xxx&quot;"
Does that work?