# ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment, connection-string

I have an Asp.net MVC5 application and have published it to `Microsoft Azure`. I first migrated my `.mdf` files to`Sql Azure Databases`. The database connection string provided in the `Azure Portal` is not working.

> [ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.]

My connection string is as follows `web.config`

```
connectionString="
    Server=tcp:dbprojectserver.database.windows.net,1433;
    Initial Catalog=db_project;
    Persist Security Info=False;
    User ID=username@servername;
    Password=kenth&amp;&amp;123;
    Encrypt=True;
    TrustServerCertificate=False;
    Connection Timeout=30;
    "
```

I believe so there is something wrong with this connection string. Any help regarding that is highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Reading from here [SQL Server Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) and following EF Db first or Model first connection string example

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/ ContextClass.csdl|res://*/ ContextClass.ssdl|res://*/ ContextClass.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=ServerName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" />
```

This is what I am using according to above example

```
<add name="ProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.csdl|res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.ssdl|res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=tcp:dbprojectserver.database.windows.net,1433;Integrated Security=False;User Id=username@servername;Password=kenth$$123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;
      " providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

It says

> Keyword not supported 'data source'

Comment: How did you get this ConectionString? Is this one really provided by the portal? Because I looked at a few samples of my own and saw only "Data Source="...", never Server=""

Comment: @Henk, yes this is what is provided by the portal

Comment: @HenkHolterman There are a few keywords that mean the same thing.

Comment: Have you seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6647089/1658906 ?

Comment: @juunas, please see the edit the section of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyword not supported: 'server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646833/keyword-not-supported-server)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when specified EF connection string on the Azure Portal in Application Service settings (Application settings -> Connection strings).

To fix it:

- Replace `&quot;` with `"`
- Specify connection string type as **Custom** but not as **SQL Database**.

Also, as I can see you do not have **Initial Catalog** in your latest example. You need to add it and specify your database in this parameter.

Finally your connection string for application settings in Azure portal should look like this:

```
metadata=res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.csdl|res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.ssdl|res://*/ ProjectWeb.Models.User.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string="Data Source=tcp:dbprojectserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<your database>;Integrated Security=False;User Id=username@servername;Password=kenth$$123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

Comment: Indeed, single tick quotes instead of XML escaping works!

Answer (score 0):

If it is an error on the code line of connection string then try remove below code from web.config file.

```
Trust Server Certificate=True
```