# Azure Functions - how to connect to local SQL Server Express database?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, database-connection, azure-functions

I am creating my first application with Azure functions and trying to connect to the local SQL Server Express database. How do I provide the connection string so that I can connect to the local SQL Server Express database successfully?

When I try to run the application locally, here is the error I get:

> System.ArgumentException occurred
>   HResult=0x80070057
>   Message=Keyword not supported: 'server'.
>   Source=
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(IDictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, IList`1 validKeywords)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

My `local.settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxx",
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "xxx"
    },

    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "RecConnectionString": {
            "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=myDB;Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=SSPI;",
            "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
        }
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "EntityFramework": "6.0.0",
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the SQL Express version you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied by the error message: **Message=Keyword not supported: 'server'.**

The error is caused by using the 'server' keyword in your connection string.

You should replace the keyword 'server' with '**Data Source**'

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=myDB;Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Alternatively, you can also modify your provider name to **`System.Data.SqlClient`** instead of updating your existing connection string.

For your reference, this issue is also similar to the previous question here at the link below:

[Keyword not supported: 'server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646833/keyword-not-supported-server)

Hope this helps.