# Connection string not working in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database=ABC; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

I am working with ASP.NET Core MVC. I have this connection string in my appsettings.json file but it doesn't seem to work. While running "dotnet ef database update" from cmd, I am getting this error **keyword not supported: 'server.'**. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is it true to assume, you're using EntityFramework for this connection ?

Comment: That is not an EF connection string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyword not supported: 'server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646833/keyword-not-supported-server)

Comment: @Nkosi, I know, that is why i'm trying to know if the OP is using it with EF which will explain the error.

Comment: Yes, I am using EF

Comment: @OrelEraki, understood. My comment was directed at the OP. The timing just made it look like I was responding to your comment when I wasn't. Either way it is a common duplicate and should be closed as such.

Comment: I've seen that answer, but that doesn't seem to resolve the issue. What should the connection string look like?

Comment: @Nkosi,@Orel Eraki This connection string is similar to the one shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologies! In my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs, I was using SQLite database provider

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
```

I changed it to the following, and it worked with my connection string.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
```

Answer (score -4):

The connection string should start of with `Data Source=`.

In Visual Studio if you open the SQL Server Object Explorer and click on the database you are wanting to connect to. The connection string will be displayed in the Properties window. The connections string should look something like this for localDb

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DbName;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=Fals
```