# Troubles Implementing Role Provider

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

It's telling me the connection string is incorrect and that "metadata" keyword is not supported.

**Connection String**: Automatically created when I generate my models

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataContext"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;
      provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
      provider connection string='data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
      initial catalog=&quot;Phase 2&quot;;
      integrated security=True;
      multipleactiveresultsets=True;
      application name=EntityFramework'" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Role Manager**: Set connectionStringName to the name of the connection string above

```
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DataContext" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

When I call the method *Roles.CreateRole* it gives me the following errors

```
An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection     object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
```

The Inner Exception

```
{"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693499/asp-net-system-data-entityclient-connection-string-help) question is any help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am able to query and update my database.  The only time this error gets thrown is when I try to create a role.  This leads me to believe that my connection string is correct.