# MVC Controller generates Exception on format of Initialization String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on MVC application came across one issue while saving the data in database.
Issue is ***"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 140"***

and my web.config file holds this code

```
<add name="ABC" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ABC;initial catalog=UPS;persist security info=True;Server=ABC;Database=XYZ;user id=AMIT;password=pASSOWRD;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />"
```

My homecontroller code where it breaks and throws an exception in the last line

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
 var Date = (DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1];
 //var Replace = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i] 
 [3].ToString().Replace("'", " \'").Replace(",","\");
 string conn = 
 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ConnectionString;
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
```

somebody please help me with this issue

Comment: You have escaped quotes in your connection string. E.g. `&quot;` probably shouldn't be in this string.

Comment: Now i can login into my application and validation is happening through database data but if i remove &quot i cant able to login only.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you able to query your database by removing the offending string?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693499/asp-net-system-data-entityclient-connection-string-help - thank you so much for your reply and i am using this format

Comment: i have solved the issue using transaction methodology per excel sheet and now i can able to save data from excel sheet to db using same web.config but changes required in code... thank you so much for you reply daniel